# html table header does not align with the table float_Thead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jquery.floatThead and my Table header doesn't align with my table when i scroll. The table header aligns properly when I re size the window even just a little bit. Here is my css:

```
table.floatThead-table {
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: gray;

}
```

Here is my application.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
var $table = $('.queue-display');
$table.floatThead();

$table.trigger('reflow');

});
```

Here is my jsfiddle link, i am not sure if you can really tell that it doesn't align:

http://jsfiddle.net/833eLyod/19/

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px; top: 60px; z-index: 1001; left: 0px; width: 643px;" aria-hidden="true" class="floatThead-floatContainer floatThead-container"><table class="queue-display                 table-striped                 table-hover                 table-condensed                 table-bordered                 unselectable floatThead-table" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-width: 1px 1px 0px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); display: table; margin: 0px; table-layout: fixed; width: 643px;"><colgroup><col style="width: 350px;"><col style="width: 72px;"><col style="width: 75px;"><col style="width: 80px;"><col style="width: 65px;"></colgroup><thead>
      <tr>

        <th class="queue-row-filename">
          <i class="fa fa-sort" data-bind="click: function() { toggleSortBy('filename') }"></i>
          filename
        </th>

        <!-- ko foreach: columns -->
        <th data-bind="attr: {'class': 'queue-row-' + $data}" class="queue-row-sticky.note">
          <!-- ko if: $parent.isSortableColumn($data) --><!-- /ko -->

          <span data-bind="text: $data">sticky.note</span>
          <span data-bind="if: $parent.isRemovableColumn($data)">
            <i class="fa fa-close" style="cursor: pointer;" data-bind="click: $parent.removeColumn">
            </i>
          </span>
        </th>

        <th data-bind="attr: {'class': 'queue-row-' + $data}" class="queue-row-taxonomy.history">
          <!-- ko if: $parent.isSortableColumn($data) --><!-- /ko -->

          <span data-bind="text: $data">taxonomy.history</span>
          <span data-bind="if: $parent.isRemovableColumn($data)">
            <i class="fa fa-close" style="cursor: pointer;" data-bind="click: $parent.removeColumn">
            </i>
          </span>
        </th>

        <th data-bind="attr: {'class': 'queue-row-' + $data}" class="queue-row-date">
          <!-- ko if: $parent.isSortableColumn($data) -->
            <i class="fa fa-sort" data-bind="click: function() { $parent.toggleSortBy($data) }"></i>
          <!-- /ko -->

          <span data-bind="text: $data">date</span>
          <span data-bind="if: $parent.isRemovableColumn($data)">
            <i class="fa fa-close" style="cursor: pointer;" data-bind="click: $parent.removeColumn">
            </i>
          </span>
        </th>

        <th data-bind="attr: {'class': 'queue-row-' + $data}" class="queue-row-queue">
          <!-- ko if: $parent.isSortableColumn($data) -->
            <i class="fa fa-sort" data-bind="click: function() { $parent.toggleSortBy($data) }"></i>
          <!-- /ko -->

          <span data-bind="text: $data">queue</span>
          <span data-bind="if: $parent.isRemovableColumn($data)">
            <i class="fa fa-close" style="cursor: pointer;" data-bind="click: $parent.removeColumn">
            </i>
          </span>
        </th>

        <th data-bind="attr: {'class': 'queue-row-' + $data}" class="queue-row-creator">
          <!-- ko if: $parent.isSortableColumn($data) -->
            <i class="fa fa-sort" data-bind="click: function() { $parent.toggleSortBy($data) }"></i>
          <!-- /ko -->

          <span data-bind="text: $data">creator</span>
          <span data-bind="if: $parent.isRemovableColumn($data)">
            <i class="fa fa-close" style="cursor: pointer;" data-bind="click: $parent.removeColumn">
            </i>
          </span>
        </th>

        <th data-bind="attr: {'class': 'queue-row-' + $data}" class="queue-row-mtime">
          <!-- ko if: $parent.isSortableColumn($data) --><!-- /ko -->

          <span data-bind="text: $data">mtime</span>
          <span data-bind="if: $parent.isRemovableColumn($data)">
            <i class="fa fa-close" style="cursor: pointer;" data-bind="click: $parent.removeColumn">
            </i>
          </span>
        </th>
        <!-- /ko -->
      </tr>
    </thead></table></div>
```

Here is my html.erb:

```
<!-- note that file_list.js will change this -->
<% content_for :title, 'Q' %>

<%= render 'q/queue/top_bar' %>
<div id="queue-app">


  <!-- note that this requires a tabindex so it can fire key press
  events -->
  <table class="queue-display
                table-striped
                table-hover
                table-condensed
                table-bordered
                unselectable"
         tabindex="0">


    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th class="queue-row-filename">
          <i class="fa fa-sort"
             data-bind="click: function() { toggleSortBy('filename') }"></i>
          filename
        </th>

        <!-- ko foreach: columns -->
        <th data-bind="attr: {'class': 'queue-row-' + $data}">
          <!-- ko if: $parent.isSortableColumn($data) -->
            <i class="fa fa-sort"
               data-bind="click: function() { $parent.toggleSortBy($data) }"></i>
          <!-- /ko -->

          <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
          <span data-bind="if: $parent.isRemovableColumn($data)">
            <i class="fa fa-close"
               style="cursor: pointer;"
               data-bind="click: $parent.removeColumn">
            </i>
          </span>
        </th>
        <!-- /ko -->
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody data-bind="foreach: {
                        data: visibleQueueFiles,
                        beforeRemove: hideQueueFileElement,
                        afterAdd: showQueueFileElement
                      }">
      <tr data-bind="css: {
                       selectedFile: selected,
                       activeFile: $parent.activeQueueFile() == $data,
                    }, attr: {'data-queue-file' : $data.id() }">
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"
                  data-bind="click: editFile">
            Edit
          </button>


          <a data-bind="click: function() { showInViewer() }"
             class="btn btn-default btn-xs">View</a>

          <span
                data-bind="text: filename,
                           style: {
                           'display' : 'inline-block',
                           'text-decoration': moved() ? 'line-through' : ''
                           }
                           ">

          </span>


          <span data-bind="if: moved">
            Moved to <span data-bind="text: moved_to_qid"></span>
          </span>

          <span data-bind="if: owner">
            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
          </span>

          <span data-bind="if: isNew">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"
               title="File added to queue"></i>
          </span>


        </td>

        <!-- ko foreach: $parent.columns -->
        <td class="qid"
            data-bind="text: $parent.displayForColumn($data),
                       attr: { 'title' : $parent.titleForColumn($data) }">
        </td>
        <!-- /ko -->


      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var app = new queue.App(<%= @queue_info.to_json.html_safe %>);

      app.run();

      window.queueApp = app;

    });
  </script>

  <%= render 'q/queue/view_modal' %>

  <copy-dialog params="queueViewModel: $root"></copy-dialog>
  <rename-dialog params="queueFiles: selectedQueueFiles"></rename-dialog>
  <%= render 'q/queue/custom_queues_modal' %>

  <%= render 'q/queue/bottom_bar' %>


</div><!-- #queue-app -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a `select{width:100px;}` The floatar is stabilised Check http://plnkr.co/edit/1xWds0kduZCIZQXv62ka?p=preview

Comment: I changed the html page  on the application and it didn't work for me. I still have a little gap between the table and the table header. The table header works fine when i resize the window even just a little bit. That's what makes it really confusing for me.

Comment: Oh ok. I got it. Get a `setTimeout(function(){$('.queue-display').trigger('reflow');},1000);`

Comment: I guess the application is heavy and DOM takes time to load, increase that number in setTimeout 1000 = 1second to suit you how long it takes up to laod up the application and 1 second after that or 2seconds after that fire a reflow it will try to adjust

Comment: ohh man that kinda worked after i added to: $(document).ready(function(){  
var $table = $('.queue-display');
$table.floatThead({autoReflow: false});

$table.trigger('reflow');

setTimeout(function(){$('.queue-display').trigger('reflow');},1000);
 
});

Comment: but still when i change my view and it adds more column to the table it doesn't work

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/suj7ws01/. When my column gets that big the view messes up again and i have to re size the window again for it align properly.

Comment: Your table is playing games with you. Actually add `<table border=1 ...` then you will see that the columns in each row dont match. I believe they are dynamically populated so make sure you always have X tds in all rows. If any row has one more or less you will run into serious issues, say if any cell doesn't have data still then populate a blank `<td></td>`

Comment: I am using knockout java if that makes a difference.

Comment: if i add table border =1 the table header doesn't even scroll

Comment: any language is fine. Just make sure you have td count same every row.

Comment: Add this to your fiddle above `<table border=1 class="queue-display
                table-striped
                table-hover
                table-condensed
                table-bordered
                unselectable" tabindex="0" style="table-layout: fixed; min-width: 1096px;"><colgroup><col style="width: 50px;"><col style="width: 72px;"><col style="width: 75px;"><col style="width: 80px;"><col style="width: 65px;"><col style="width: 80px;"><col style="width: 65px;"></colgroup>`

Comment: you need 7 th where as you have provided 5. I guess when you change your th count it will do the job

Comment: so add 2 more th to your thead > tr

Comment: after adding this setTimeout(function(){$('.queue-display').trigger('reflow');},1000); when i have 5 it works like a charm anything more it messes up

Comment: after adding this `<table border=1 class="queue-display table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-bordered unselectable" tabindex="0" style="table-layout: fixed; min-width: 1096px;"><colgroup><col style="width: 50px;"><col style="width: 72px;"><col style="width: 75px;"><col style="width: 80px;"><col style="width: 65px;"><col style="width: 80px;"><col style="width: 65px;"></colgroup>` the table header doesn't even show up

Comment: Do you know where you are declaring the TH ?

Comment: Can you count number of TH in your application please. Mkae sure it is 7 since you are populating 7 TDs per row

Comment: sorry for the late replay it is populating 7 <th. It is declared under <thead>. but when you scroll the table header doesn't align with the table.  I think the <th is getting created by javascript knockout. I will attach the html code above.

Comment: Also look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/6tpp23dd/I can't get the table header to scroll in jsfiddle but it scrolls in real application but the header is all bunched up when you scroll

Comment: okay i think i have a solution but i don't know how to go about it unless you can help me. I need to call afterrender after knockout builds the table: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html but how do i go about write the afterrender and adding to the code.

Comment: Also i am going to add my show.html.erb at the top to see if that might be helpful to you.

Comment: So i finally got the knockout to return afterRender but i am still having the same problem. `<tbody data-bind="foreach: {
                        data: visibleQueueFiles,
                        beforeRemove: hideQueueFileElement,
                        afterAdd: showQueueFileElement, afterRender: showAfterRender 
                      }">   this.showAfterRender = function () {

          var $table = $('.queue-display');
           $table.floatThead({useAbsolutePositioning: false});
          $table.trigger('reflow');

       }
`

Comment: Never mind i finally got it to work by adding this: setTimeout(function(){$('.queue-display').trigger('reflow');},1000); even though it takes few second to align it self it works. unless you know a way to make it instant i am happy with this.

Comment: I take that back it's not working. It's working for some view and not the others.

Comment: joyBlanks do you know why its working for some views not the others. I also posted something here: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9193580

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87204/discussion-between-reazur-rahman-and-joyblanks).